# Does anyone have a tool which can automatically attempt to refactor javascript to a more prototype/oo style?

Tags: javascript, automated-refactoring

It looks to me like it might be possible to, in many cases, automatically perform some of the refactoring required to turn a functional and/or class style javascript source into a more prototype/non-class based oo source.

Has anyone made a serious attempt at writing a tool that does this kind of automatic refactoring?

Comment: Well, the functional aspect of JavaScript is its core mechanism, so you cannot replace that with something else (nor would you want to). As for switching from "class style" to "prototype style", do you have before/after code?

Comment: If that were possible, it would be *very* difficult. These kinds of things are sometimes hard for human programmers to do--how do you expect an automated tool to do it? It depends entirely on the implementation of the class-based system.

Comment: Imagine a tool-suite that can automatically identify code-smells and suggest where re-factorings might be appropriate. It could help a little bit with the decision making about where to change the code, and a lot with the process of searching through a code-base for improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that, to date (23-Nov-2010) no such tools exist/have been attempted.

Answer (score 0):

Tell your product manager that we need to write app-2.0